# EXCEL: Adding "Comment" Column to Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am adding a column to the right of a pivot table. In this column I make comments about figures that are in the rows of the pivot table. However, If I want to filter pivot table content, I want that comment to also collapse... But the comment column would need to be a field of the pivot table.

See attached for illustration. The highlighted column is the rightmost column of the pivot table.

How can I do this : PivotTable w/comment column?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the comment in the source data in an additional column.